# How can we obtain the accuracy of each fold separately with the '-v' option in liblinear or livsvm?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm, cross-validation

In liblinear and libsvm, the option `-v k` allows us to run k-fold cross validation. But to test statistical significance, I need the accuracy obtained on each fold. Of course there is the long drawn way to create each fold and then run train and test k times, but I was wondering if there is a way to get the accuracy of each fold even when I use the `-v` option.

I think liblinear and libsvm will have the same answer to my question. Please correct me if I am wrong about this.